# Plot the expression using NIntegrate for the limiting case

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I need to plot the below equations:

$W^{+}(x,\tau,\alpha)]=-\frac{2m}{\pi\alpha}\exp[{\alpha x}]\times\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{G(\omega,\tau_c)}{1+\omega^2}\cos(2\tau_c\omega\sqrt{1+\omega^2}-2\tan^{-1}(\omega) + \alpha x\omega)\text{d}\omega + 2mx$

and

$W^{-}(x,\tau,\alpha)]=-\frac{2m}{\pi\alpha}\exp[{\alpha x}]\times\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{G(\omega,\tau_c)}{1+\omega^2}\cos(2\tau_c\omega\sqrt{1+\omega^2}-2\tan^{-1}(\omega) + \alpha x\omega)\text{d}\omega $

Here,  $\tau_c=\tau\alpha^3$; $G(\omega,\tau_c)=\exp[\tau_c\sqrt{1+\omega^2}(1-\omega^2)]$ and $m=0.2$.

For $\alpha=0$ the profile should be symmetric, and for increasing $\alpha$ the profile becomes asymmetric across the x-axis. Here is my naive attempt

```
 G[\[Omega]_,\[Tau]C_] := Exp[\[Tau]C Sqrt[1+\[Omega]^2](1-\[Omega]^2)]   
  position[x_] := -2(mSlope/\[Alpha] \[Pi])Exp[\[Alpha] x] NIntegrate[G[\[Omega],\[Tau]C] Cos[2 \[Tau]C \[Omega] Sqrt[1+\[Omega]^2]-2ArcTan[\[Omega]]+\[Alpha] x \[Omega] ]/(1+\[Omega]^2),{\[Omega],0,\[Infinity]}] + 2 mSlope x
    positionLeft[x_] := -2(mSlope/\[Alpha] \[Pi])Exp[\[Alpha] x] NIntegrate[G[\[Omega],\[Tau]C] Cos[2 \[Tau]C \[Omega] Sqrt[1+\[Omega]^2]-2ArcTan[\[Omega]]+\[Alpha] x \[Omega] ]/(1+\[Omega]^2),{\[Omega],0,\[Infinity]}] 
\[Tau]C = 2; \[Alpha] = 0.001;\[mSlope] = 0.2
Plot[positionLeft[k], {k, 0.0, -10}]
Plot[position[k], {k, 0.0, 10}]
```

Output

[image]
[image]

At $x=0$, the above plot does not show discontinuity in the profile slopes.

Can anyone help out on how to plot these type of equations and what type of NInegrate scheme one should apply?

P.S: The above figure and equations are from Eq. 5 from [this article](https://doi.org/10.1016/0956-7151(91)90291-8).

Thanks

Comment: Could you give a reference for where you got the plot in your question?

Comment: @J.M. I have included the Ref.

Comment: @newstudent What did you try so far yourself in Mathematica?

Comment: @RolfMertig I have edited the post with my attempt and obtained output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your equations `(mSlope/α π)` should be `(mSlope/(α π))`. Your value of `τC = 2` appears questionable since `τC == τ*α^3` and with `α = 10^-3`, `τ` would be very large. I have used `τC = 1*^-6`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

G[ω_, τC_] := Exp[τC Sqrt[1 + ω^2] (1 - ω^2)]

position[x_] := Module[{xx = SetPrecision[x, 20]},
  -2 (mSlope/(α π)) Exp[α xx] NIntegrate[
     G[ω, τC] Cos[
        2 τC ω Sqrt[1 + ω^2] - 
         2 ArcTan[ω] + α xx ω]/(1 + ω^2), {\
ω, 0, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> 20] + 2 mSlope xx]

positionLeft[x_] := Module[{xx = SetPrecision[x, 20]},
  -2 (mSlope/(α π)) Exp[α xx] NIntegrate[
    G[ω, τC] Cos[
       2 τC ω Sqrt[1 + ω^2] - 
        2 ArcTan[ω] + α xx ω]/(1 + ω^2), \
{ω, 0, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]]

W[x_] := Piecewise[{{position[x], x >= 0}, {positionLeft[x], x < 0}}]

τC = 1*^-6; α = 10^-3; mSlope = 1/5;

Plot[W[k]/mSlope, {k, -60, 60}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much !